# Add “selected” Class to the Menu Item - MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, class, navbar, selected

I fallow this tutorial ([link](http://bubblogging.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/mvc-add-selected-class-to-menu/)) how to add "selected" class to the menu in MVC, in other words this tutorial shows how to create navigator menu in MVC, when you click on nav button it stays selected.

But when I write this code in begining

```
using <span class="skimlinks-unlinked">System.Web</span>;
using <span class="skimlinks-unlinked">System.Web.Mvc</span>;

namespace <span class="skimlinks-unlinked">AdminRole.HtmlHelpers</span>
{
   ...
}
```

My Visual Studio 2012 shows error in all of this area

```
<span class="skimlinks-unlinked">
```

and it says Identifier expected?

What identifier? Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solve it...

This code:

```
using <span class="skimlinks-unlinked">System.Web</span>;
using <span class="skimlinks-unlinked">System.Web.Mvc</span>;

namespace <span class="skimlinks-unlinked">AdminRole.HtmlHelpers</span>
```

Rewrite to:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AdminRole.HtmlHelpers
```

Now it works :)